# Is a transaction with a non-segwit input STILL considered malleable? If so how?

Tags: segregated-witness, transaction-malleability, witness-data

Below are a few examples of witness malleability, along with reasons why I believe they are no longer valid:

**DER Malleability**

- For every DER signature with (r,s), there exists 2 valid 's' values -> BIP146 requires low 's' only

**scriptSig Malleability**

- Can add OP_NOP -> "scriptsig-not-pushonly" error
- Can add OP_1 at start of scriptSig -> "Stack size must be exactly one after execution" error
- Can add, say, OP_PUSHDATA1 OP_0 -> "Data push larger than necessary" error
- Can add OP_1 OP_DROP at start of scriptSig -> "scriptsig-not-pushonly" error

In summary, it appears the Bitcoin team has done a pretty good job of plugging the holes in non-segwit witness data malleability, so I'm not clear why one of the major benefits of segwit to this day is listed as preventing malleability (I get that Segwit is a more absolute solution to this problem, given the witness data isn't part of txid and hence txid is immutable).

The only reasons I can think of why non-segwit malleability would remain an issue is if some of the witness malleability attack vectors listed above are still valid if a transaction is submitted directly to miner (even if rejected by other nodes), or if a non-negligible portion of nodes still hadn't updated these software changes from 2016 etc.

Comment: Good question, i think it is a good illustration of the infamously confusing terminology in the Bitcoin world. There is more than one malleability. :p (We need a Benevolent Bitcoin Terminology Dictator to assign different names to different things.)

Comment: @AntoinePoinsot So... the term malleability is malleable?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are conflating two types of malleability:

- The first one is txid malleability of a presigned transaction: two (or more) parties can't trustlessly build a chain of unconfirmed transactions if tweaking the witness data of any of them would invalidate the whole chain.
- The second one is third-party malleability of any transaction. If a third-party (ie not the issuer of the transaction) can turn a valid transaction broadcast to the network into another valid transaction with a different identifier, it can (among other undesirable effects) hinder the propagation of a transaction and potentially of blocks themselves by affecting compact blocks relay.

Segregated witness is a fix for the former, but not the latter. The rules you mention that enforce a stricter encoding have to do with the latter.

You would never be able to use presigned transactions trustlessly if simply changing the witness data of a spent transaction would change its txid. [0] Simply creating a new signature would change the txid (no matter the strict DER encoding). And in any multi-party situation just using different spending paths would lead to the same transaction having different identifiers. To illustrate, take a simple 1-of-2 multisig (`<1> <A> <B> <2> OP_CHECKMULTISIG`). You can try to carve-out any strict encoding rule, the txid of the spending transaction is always going to change depending on whether the script is satisfied by providing a signature for `A` or `B`.

On the other hand, separating the witness data from the txid does not fix third-party malleability. Because you need a new identifier to refer to the complete transaction anyways, as that's what gets propagated (it's called the `wtxid`). But having strict encoding rules (like minimal push, `NULLDUMMY`, etc..) do help to build the tooling that permits to create non-malleable scripts. See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116282/101498) for more about this.

[0] Another way of fixing this is by having signatures not commit to the spent coin, and assume you'll always be able to re-create a new transaction and re-bind the signatures to it. It's a powerful approach which comes with a different set of tradeoffs. Look for "BIP118", "ANYPREVOUT" or "NOINPUT" for more about this.

Answer (score 3):

The status of BIP146 is “withdrawn”. Even for segwit inputs, high-s ECDSA signatures are only non-standard but consensus valid.

I don’t know about the other malleability issues in detail, but would suspect that they might also be just non-standard but valid.

So, at least some of the above can still be inserted into the blockchain by block authors even when such transactions do not propagate on the network.